# Python pandas groupby: how to use variables in different columns to create a new one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Consider the following `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c0':['1980']*3+['1990']*2+['2000']*3,
                   'c1':['x','y','z']+['x','y']+['x','y','z'],
                   'c2':range(8)  })

     c0 c1  c2
0  1980  x   0
1  1980  y   1
2  1980  z   2
3  1990  x   3
4  1990  y   4
5  2000  x   5
6  2000  y   6
7  2000  z   7
```

I want to do the following using `pandas`'s `groupby` over `c0`:

1. Group rows based on `c0` (indicate year).
2. In each group, subtract the value of `c2` for `y` (in `c1`) from the values of `c2`.
3. Add a new column `c3` collecting those values.

The final result is

```
     c0 c1  c2  c3
0  1980  x   0  -1
1  1980  y   1   0
2  1980  z   2   1
3  1990  x   3  -1
4  1990  y   4   0
5  2000  x   5  -1
6  2000  y   6   0
7  2000  z   7   1
```

I was able to get the result without `groupby` like the following:

```
dic = {}

for yr in df['c0'].unique():
    
    cond1 = ( df['c0']==yr )
    tmp = df.loc[cond1,:].copy()
    
    cond2 = ( tmp['c1']=='y' )
    val = tmp.loc[cond2,'c2'].to_numpy()
    
    tmp['c3'] = tmp['c2'] - val
    
    dic[yr] = tmp


pd.concat([dic['1980'],dic['1990'],dic['2000']])
```

It works but does not look great. I tried `transform` and `apply` for `groupby`, but could not figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can broadcast `y` value with `transform` after hiding all non-y rows for the group using `where`:

```
df['c3' ] = df['c2'] - df.where(df['c1'] == 'y').groupby(df['c0'])['c2'].transform('max')
print(df)

# Output
     c0 c1  c2   c3
0  1980  x   0 -1.0
1  1980  y   1  0.0
2  1980  z   2  1.0
3  1990  x   3 -1.0
4  1990  y   4  0.0
5  2000  x   5 -1.0
6  2000  y   6  0.0
7  2000  z   7  1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is something new with multiindex selection

```
s = df.set_index(['c0', 'c1'])
s['c3'] = s['c2'] - s['c2'].xs('y', level=1)
s = s.reset_index()
```

Result

```
     c0 c1  c2  c3
0  1980  x   0  -1
1  1980  y   1   0
2  1980  z   2   1
3  1990  x   3  -1
4  1990  y   4   0
5  2000  x   5  -1
6  2000  y   6   0
7  2000  z   7   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
df['c3'] = (df.groupby('c0')
            .apply(lambda g: g['c2'].values-g.loc[g['c1'].eq('y'), 'c2'].values)
            .explode().values)
```

Output:

```
     c0 c1  c2  c3
0  1980  x   0  -1
1  1980  y   1   0
2  1980  z   2   1
3  1990  x   3  -1
4  1990  y   4   0
5  2000  x   5  -1
6  2000  y   6   0
7  2000  z   7   1
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df['c3']  = (df.groupby('c0')
               .apply(lambda g: g['c2']-g['c2'][g['c1'].eq('y')].values)
               .reset_index(drop=True)
           )
```

```
df
     c0 c1  c2  c3
0  1980  x   0  -1
1  1980  y   1   0
2  1980  z   2   1
3  1990  x   3  -1
4  1990  y   4   0
5  2000  x   5  -1
6  2000  y   6   0
7  2000  z   7   1
```